# PDF Editor for angular 7

Tags: angular, pdf, canvas, html5-canvas, pdf-generation

I'm working on an application that currently loads pdfs from file on the server and draws highlights on them based on coordinates before sending it back to the client. However we've found this process to be too slow as an API call needs to be made each time the user chooses to highlight different text, thus we need a client side solution.

Are there any clientside pdf editors that work well with Angular 7 that can do this? Here is the process.

**1.) User clicks on a document**

**2.)Server will send the pdf to client along with all the coordinates corresponding to possible values of interest that the user may be looking for.**

**3.) As the user clicks on controls, the client will draw highlights directly on the PDF based on those coordinates without need for a server call.**

I imagine the solution to this would either have this capability built in or at least allow me access to the underlying HTML canvas element so that I can do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [www.pdftron.com](http://www.pdftron.com) or [ej2.syncfusion.com](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/)
but it will cost money)